# Set the number of Threads (Consumers) on HornetQ 2.2.14.Final

Tags: multithreading, jboss, threadpool, producer-consumer, hornetq

I have an EJB that is message driven which receives messages from a `HornetQ (2.2.14.Final)`. The application in question runs on `JBoss 5.1.0.GA`. When I set the number of consumers of my queue to 5:

```
<activation-config-property>
       <activation-config-property-name>maxSession</activation-config-property-name>
       <activation-config-property-value>5</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

and I have 7 different Groups to process and that are called almost at the same time (by `message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "Group-X");`, the Queue only uses 2 consumers (Thread-2 and Thread-3) to process my 7 different Groups. Why are not used 5 consumers/threads?

Then, if I set the number of consumers to 7, only 5 are being used... How does the allocation of messages to the consumers works? It is necessary to set anything else?